# Sqlalchemy/Geoalchemy2 radius search returning empty list

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, geoalchemy2, geoalchemy

I want to implement a radius search on my location table (on mariadb) that has latitude and longitude stored. Now I would like to get all locations within a certain amount of km. This is my attempt but it always returns an empty list:

```py
from geoalchemy2.elements import WKTElement    
from sqlalchemy import func
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
    
def get_locations_in_radius(db: Session, radius: int, lat: float, lng: float):
    locations = db.query(models.Location).filter(
        func.ST_Distance_Sphere(
            func.ST_GeomFromText(f"POINT({models.Location.lng} {models.Location.lat})"),
            func.ST_GeomFromText(f"POINT({lng} {lat})")
        ) <= radius
    ).all()

    return locations
```

Comment: I found a workaround: If I directly add the geom to the table/model and reference it, it works. This does not explain why my original approach does not work. Maybe models.Location.lng and models.Location.lat does not load in the fstring?

Comment: If you're converting the literal values of `models.Location.lng` to a string, it won't be the actual column reference that is expected - but just the converted value to a string - just as if you'd called `print` on the value. That is not what you want, since you want a reference to the column, not the stringified value.